# Replace a part of dataframe with new data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have *data1* and *data2*, and I need *data3*, that replaces certain regions of *data1* with *data2*.

I use this method to update the data, but actually several columns need to be updated and it would be tedious.

Do you know a more simple way?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data1 <- tibble(date=date("2017-11-1") + c(1:10),
            a=sample(100,10),b=sample(100,10))

data2 <- tibble(date=date("2017-11-1") + c(1:8),
            a=sample(100,8))

data_bind <- left_join(data1, data2, by=("date"))
data_bind$a.x[!is.na(data_bind$a.y)] <- data_bind$a.y[!is.na(data_bind$a.y)]
data_bind %>% select(-a.y) %>% dplyr::rename(a=a.x)
```

Comment: Please write `library(wherever these exotic functions come from)` to make the example reproducible in a new R session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the `data.table`-package is better suited for such a task. Using:

```
# create a vector with names from 'data2' that are not used to join by
nms <- names(data2)[-1]

# load the 'data.table'-package
library(data.table)

# convert the dataframes to data,table's
setDT(data1)
setDT(data2)

# join and update the column in 'data1' with the matching values from 'data2'
data1[data2, on = 'date', (nms) := mget(paste0('i.',nms))][]
```

gives:

> ```
>           date  a  b
>  1: 2017-11-02 21 11
>  2: 2017-11-03 22 12
>  3: 2017-11-04 23 13
>  4: 2017-11-05 24 14
>  5: 2017-11-06 25 15
>  6: 2017-11-07 26 16
>  7: 2017-11-08 27 17
>  8: 2017-11-09 28 18
>  9: 2017-11-10  9 19
> 10: 2017-11-11 10 20
> ```

What this does:

- With `setDT(data1)` you convert the dataframes/tibbles to a data.table.
- With `data1[data2, on = 'date']` you can do a join the data.table-way.
- By adding `(nms) := mget(paste0('i.',nms))` to the join, you tell `data.table` to update the columns in `data1` with the columns that are also present in `data2` only where the dates match.

---

As an alternative approach you could also reshape both datasets into long format and then do the join:

```
library(data.table)
melt(data1, id = 'date')[melt(data2, id = 'date')
                         , on = .(date, variable)
                         , value := i.value
                         ][, dcast(.SD, date ~ variable)]
```

A translation of this approach to the `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(data1, key, value, -1) %>% 
  left_join(., gather(data2, key, value, -1), by = c('date','key')) %>% 
  mutate(value.x = ifelse(!is.na(value.y), value.y, value.x)) %>% 
  select(date, key, value = value.x) %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

Both will give you the same output.

---

Used data:

```
data1 <- data.frame(date = as.Date("2017-11-1") + c(1:10), a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
data2 <- data.frame(date = as.Date("2017-11-1") + c(1:8), a = 21:28)
```